# Deserializing json object that has a hashmap fails

Tags: json, jackson

I am running into problem of not being able to deseriablize a  class which has a defintion of hashmap inside it.

My class is defined as follows :

```
   public class <T extends Serializable> MyClass1 {
       private Map<String,List<MyClass2<T>>> entity;
       boolean moreData=false;
       public Map<String,List<MyClass2<T>>> getEntity() {
         return entity;
       }

      public void setEntity(Map<String,List<MyClass2<T>>> entity) {
         this.entity = entity;
      }
      public boolean isMoreDataAvailable()
      {
        return moreData;
      } 
   }
```

Serializing the contents of the class produces an output such as this :

```
ObjectMapper om = getObjectMapper();
    om.writeValueAsString(myclass1inst);
    {
        "MyClass1" : {
          "entity" : {
             "java.util.HashMap" : {
                 "SITE_ADD" : {
                 "java.util.ArrayList" : [ {
                   "MyClass2" : {
                   "priority" : 3,
                     "groupName" : null,
                     "payload" : {
                       "MyClass3" : {
                        "networkType" : "HIGH_SPEED_LAN",
                        "nativeSite" : true
                     }
                   "groupOrderType" : null,
                   "entityGuid" : null
                   }
                 } ]
              }
            }
          },
          "moreDataAvailable" : false
         }
      }
```

The problem is deserialization is failing for me with this exception.

```
ObjectMapper om = getObjectMapper();
om.readValue(content, MyClass1.class);
```

> 2013-06-27 02:55:47,822 [[ACTIVE]  Error while deserializing push
>   request: Invalid type id 'SITE_ADD' (for id type 'Id.class'): no such
>   class found (through reference chain: MyClass1["entity"])

Why should json think the string site_add is of type Id.class.

On reading the jackson json documentation I find the HashMap has to registered as a follows :

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

> Map result = mapper.readValue(src, new
>   TypeReference>() { });

Should I have to implement a **@jsondeserialable** to define custom deserialization. Please provide me your suggestions.

Here is the code on object initialization

```
        public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

            // to remove wrapping of root element
            om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);

            om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

            // to handle inheritence
            om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,
                           JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT);

            // to ignore getters which doesnt have setters


            om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS, false);



           // to ignore extra properties during deserialization
            om.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                 false);
            return om;
         }
```

In the above example the variable T points to MyClass3.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing some details on how `ObjectMapper` is initialized. Looks like "default typing" was enabled, which results in difference between serialization, deserialization. Also, you are not specifying type variable `T` anywhere; so things work as if `T` was `java.lang.Object`

Comment: I tested with disabling default typing, that seems to work, since the exception is now gone, but if default typing not enabled then I believe that child class deserialization will not work, would it ?

Comment: It really depends on kinds of objects. Instead of default typing, one may be able to use explicit type info with `@JsonTypeInfo` (to specify which types are polymorphic, and include ids for those). But to give more help, actual type definitions are needed.